# How to get around overloading an operator for a pointer to a struct? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword, priority-queue

I have been stuck on this problem for many hours, but I have a feeling there is a trivial solution that I am not seeing. I am trying to use a priority_queue to create a MinHeap of pointers to a struct I defined. My issue lies in having to overload the > operator for the pointer to this struct (which I know is not possible) in order to match the priority_queue template. This is my last resort attempt to use the stl priority_queue before I decided to ditch it and write my own heap code.

The relevant snippets of my code are: (i) part the struct definition:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    int frequency;
    bool operator>( const Node& other ) const{
        return frequency > other.frequency;
    }
};
```

(ii) priority queue initialization:

```
priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,greater<Node*> > q;
```

And (iii) the for loop constructing the initial heap (assume int_array has been initialized):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZEOFINTARRAY; i++)
{
    Node *n = new Node;
    n->frequency = int_array[i];
    q.push(n);
}
```

Currently, the elements in this "heap" are returned FIFO, and no sorting happens. I assume this is because the priority comparison checks the pointer and elements earlier in an array are located lower in memory. Please give me any tips on how I could accomplish this.

PS. Sorry if this post does not adhere to stackoverflow standards (I tried my best to follow the rules but it is my first post). I welcome all criticism so I can never make the same mistakes again.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot use Node as a value type in the queue? also note since this is tagged C++, there is no need for the `typedef struct Node Node;` and it might be a good idea to give your Node struct a constructor to save some typing

Comment: @stijn I do that because the struct also contains a few Node* members that I left out of here;  these Node* members are also what prevents me from making Node the type in the queue, because later on in the code I have to essentially rebuild the queue (the code does Huffman Encoding)

Comment: rebuilding still seems possible if you implement a swap for your Node, no? Or does that cause performance issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a generic way would be to implement a sort of `deref_greater` which is just like `std::greater` but dereferences the input args first.

```
template<class T>
struct deref_greater : public std::binary_function<T, T, bool>
{
  bool operator()( const T& _Left, const T& _Right ) const
  {
    return *_Left > *_Right;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than overloading the `>` operator on your Node class, you could implement a comparator for `Node*` pointers:

```
struct NodeGreater
{
    bool operator() ( const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs ) const
    {
        if ( lhs == 0 || rhs == 0 )
        {
            // Perhaps throw an exception here...
        }

        return lhs->frequency > rhs->frequency;
    }
};

priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,NodeGreater> q;
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much.
I guess I wasn't familiar enough with the priority_queue and I didn't know that I could write my own comparator to use in the class Compare slot of its template. This is a good learning experience.